# Child routing using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am very much new to angular 2. I was trying to build a simple application with Login and Dashboard Pages. I need to understand how to apply the routing as my application needs.

Login page is an independent route config, but i want when use signed in, new new dashboard page comes with navigation bar and its own `<router-outlet>`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register-user', component: RegisterUserComponent },
    //APPLICATION ROUTES WITH OWN <router-outlet>
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
]
```

**Earlier in angular 1, we have used ui-router with abstract state and child states.**

Please suggest how we can accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Working plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/MqNv6RyQvzsiZTp0Dkpf?p=preview

Create one ContainerComponent & it should hold its own router-outlet & routerLinks.

By default, always load to anyComponent using redirectTo

```
{ path: 'component-two', component: ComponentTwo,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'child-one', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'child-one', component: ChildOne },
      { path: 'child-two', component: ChildTwo }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose u have a submodule inside main module.

So App module and login sub module

[image: submodule]

directory structure of main Module

[image: main module directory]

**app.routing.module.ts** something looks like this

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component:LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: Constants.LOGINROUTE, component:LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

and corresponding
**login.routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: Constants.LOGINROUTE, component: LoginComponent}
  ])],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

and **dashboard.routing.module.ts** will look like this

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: Constants.DASHBOARDROUTE,  component: DashboardComponent}
  ])],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

correspoding include login.routing.module.ts in the login.module.ts and same for dashboard.routing.module.ts

Comment: is that possible for you to send me a small sample.

Comment: like that would be really nice if you can share html implementation as well.

Comment: ya sure. shoot up you email.

Comment: please send email to this id => ravimittal16@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my project.

**This is used for lazy-loading for child route:**

You should use `loadChildren` like this in your main `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
{ path: 'crisis-center',
  loadChildren: 'app/modules/crisis-center/crisis.module#CrisisCenterModule'
 },
```

And then remove `component` from your `app-module.ts file` in below code :

**app.module.ts :**

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
        // ,AdminModule 
       ],
      declarations: [ ],
      providers: [ ],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path:  'dashboard',                  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  },
  { path: 'crisis-center',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/crisis-center/crisis.module#CrisisCenterModule'
  },
  { path:  '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path:  '**',                         component: PageNotFound},

];
```

Now fine.When the `router` navigates to this route, it uses the `loadChildren` string to dynamically load the `AdminModule`. Then it adds the `AdminModule` routes to its current route configuration. Finally, it loads the requested route to the destination admin component.

**You can also use this ( children[ ] ) in your `routing` file and can give separate component for each child routes:**

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: CrisisDetailComponent,
            canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And then add all the components into your particular `module.ts` file , like this:

```
import { NgModule                   }       from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule               }       from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule                }       from '@angular/forms';
import { CrisisCenterRoutingModule  }       from './crisis-center-routing.module';
import { CrisisCenterComponent      }       from './crisis-center.component';
import { CrisisListComponent        }       from './crisis-list.component';
import { CrisisDetailComponent      }       from './crisis-detail.component';
import { CrisisCenterHomeComponent  }       from './crisis-center-home.component';
import { CrisisService              }       from './crisis.service';

 @NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule,CrisisCenterRoutingModule,FormsModule, ],
  declarations: [CrisisCenterComponent ,CrisisListComponent,CrisisDetailComponent,CrisisCenterHomeComponent ],
  providers: [ CrisisService ],
})

export class CrisisCenterModule {}
```